# AWS Lambda suddenly not working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

I've been using AWS Lambda to run my node scripts for the past 2/3 weeks and today suddenly I'm getting https://lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/login/invocations ERROR on my console, is anyone having the same error?
Can someone shine some light on this error?

Comment: I'm getting the same for all of my us-east-1 hosted lambdas, seems like they have some issues in the region: http://status.aws.amazon.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question

Comment: @Rob i'm trying to figure out why my apps aren't running.

Comment: @Altoids I understand that, but stackoverflow is for programming questions

Comment: @Rob As a fellow programmer, can you point me in the right direction where I can ask other programmers how to solve this issue or figure out what's happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lambda is experiencing issues in `us-east-1` at the moment.

If you are testing in `us-east-1`, that might be it.

You can check status [here](http://status.aws.amazon.com/).